# Displaying Page list items in RSS gives wrong title

Tags: rss, 2007, xslt

I have an external site at which I'm displaying news using Sharepoint Pages. I would like to publish these news pages using RSS, which works fine. But the title is the file name without the file extension. Therefore all spaces are removed.

I would like to use another column (from the page list item) as the title of the entries in the RSS feed. How can this be done, without too much work? In this case I don't mind a quick and dirty solution :)

Comment: Is the site for the RSS feed a SharePoint site in the same environment?

Comment: Aha, I missed the comment :) Nope, it's a Sharepoint Portal site  in a completely different environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out [RSSBus](http://www.rssbus.com/products/sharepoint/). I haven't tried it out but it looks like an easy way to [customize SharePoint's RSS feeds](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2009/05/19/customize-sharepoint-rss-feeds.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To customize RSS feeds the best option is to create a PageAdaptor for listfeed.aspx one such way is mentioned [here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/09/29/modifying-sharepoint-rss-feeds-using-a-custom-control-adapter-implementing-delta-encoding.aspx).

You can follow the same code once you get the XML tell which fields you want to display

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't seen an answer to my comment, here is my best guess. If the site you are using to publish the pages is part of the same site collection, you can show those using a content query web part and select what fields you want to display. This would look like an RSS web part, but would ba more customizable to your needs.